# Get UI language name in javascript

Tags: javascript, language

I need to get the name of the current UI language in a javascript file. I know the following trick:

```
SP.Res.lcid
```

But that gets the the LCID. What I really need is the two-letter iso name (like 'en', 'fr', etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a JS object and fetch the values using the LCID:

```
var CultureNames = { 1033:"en", 1036:"fr" };//Store it in a utility file somewhere.

var currentCultureName = CultureNames[SP.Res.lcid]; //will return 'en' if current culture is english.
```

Comment: To avoid having to keep a utility file around, I eventually used javascript to read the 'lang' attribute of the 'html'-tag. With a substring I can get 'en' out of 'en-us'. The reason I did this is that I have another library which keeps languages but in the two-letter format. It's a bit silly to keep two such repositories. Now I just hope that SharePoint will continue to mention that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.name
```

`Sys.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is the server CurrentUICulture in JSON.

This is created by the page's `ScriptManager` and to it be available you need to set its property `EnableScriptGlobalization` to `true`.

I think this is enabled by default in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

I created a JavaScript library to handle your requirement (returns the culture name from a decimal lcid value)

The mapping comes from this page: [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) (Windows 7)

Practically inside the library there is JSON object with the values and two methods to get them.

The Culture name is the full one (for example en-US for 1033) you can slice the string if you need only the first two letters.

You can find more information on my blog:

[LCID JavaScript Helper Library](http://www.crmanswers.net/2014/06/lcid-javascript-helper-library.html)

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2013 JSOM API you could utilize [SP.ServerSettings.getGlobalInstalledLanguages Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj850983.aspx) to retrieve all the installed languages, like this:

```
function getInstalledLanguages(success,error) 
{
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var languages = SP.ServerSettings.getGlobalInstalledLanguages(ctx,15);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
       function()
       { 
          success(languages);     
       },
       error);    
}
```

and then find the corresponding language by `lcid`:

```
getInstalledLanguages(
     function(languages)
     { 
         var lcid = parseInt(SP.Res.lcid);  //get current locale
         var language = languages.filter(function(l) {
                          return l.get_lcid() === lcid; 
                       })[0];
         var langTag =  language.get_languageTag();   
         var langCode = langTag.split('-')[0];          
         console.log(langCode);     
     },
     function(sender,args)
     {
         console.log(args.get_message());
     });
```